# How do I find the answer to complete elliptic integral of the second kind without computer (i.e. with paper and pen)?

Tags: elliptic-integrals

I know that $$E(\theta|k^2)=\int_0^\theta{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}}\,d\phi.$$

I want to find $E(k)$ where $k=0.36$.

With a website I computed it to be approximately $1.518$.

How can I find the answer without computer?

Comment: You (famously) cannot compute it explicitly

Comment: You could calculate Riemann sums. $\sin\theta$ and square roots can be calculated by Taylor series.

Comment: You want $\,E(k):=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta.$ See Wikipedia article [Elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Comment: You can use descending Landen transformation to relate $E(k) $ with $E(l) $ where $l=(1-\sqrt{1-k^2})/(1+\sqrt{1-k^2})$ and $l<k$. Using this transformation a few times you will reach a value of $l$ which is small enough and then you can evaluate using the series obtained from term by term integration.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) under computation gives a series.  The terms seem to decrease as powers of $2$ so it might not take too many.  The $c_n$ are also decreasing, so it may be better yet.

Comment: The Wikipedia article also gives an algorithm using the arithmetic-geometric mean which converges quite quickly, unless $k$ is very close to 1. Beware that some people (like [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=EllipticE%280.36%5E2%29)) use the convention that $$E(k)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-k\sin^2(\theta)}\;d\theta$$

Comment: Here is a [Python version of the AGM algorithm](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVUcFyhCAUu_sVmekF3LW70u2hnTrTix_ypGgZV6VI_78PmOrKKQkPkkDvlwkThW_YyS0-wNkz1h8fik87B-NJh-LL9DD3u3XBaiXG5vr8Kt8L8LI9RjQN6kzjcp7PiVpugjfh18-JEng0Ic1ozEgx1CihEx2YRXtRo-K9fE3HIpsmvDLu4rhKtL1ud_aLh4Wd4WkejHiTeyg6p4sF4YRB4gKVS7JQsrDNPeX0cXwXY1ZOeYG48TQ9TOv_sFQSxx3Kx1PHXrlG2UBtdMXpUCXViSlj9VXyhrPRVR1dc8R2F_gTqFsFv0SFVuIDtanql718svaGxt0lPlr7B9lybPE=&lang=python), running on the SageMathCell server.

Comment: FWIW, SageMath has the [EllipticE](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/special.html#sage.functions.special.EllipticE) function, but it uses the same convention as Wolfram Alpha.